# Allow '/' in OWASP Encoder By using encodeForHTML method

Tags: java, security, xss, owasp

I need to sanitize the Http Parameter value to prevent xss attack. I am using the below owasp jar.
**esapi-2.1.0.1.jar**

I have parameter date which contains the value separating by '/'. 
**date=20/10/2017**

Here is code segment I am using to encode the value.

```
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.Encoder;

String s = "20/10/2017";
String ts = encoder.encodeForHTML(s);
System.out.println(ts);
```

It is printing **20&#x2f;10&#x2f;2017** But I need to allow '/' and the value should be like **20/10/2017**

I looked up into the source code and there were some characters allowed, and declared in the final Array.

```
private final static char[]     IMMUNE_HTML = { ',', '.', '-', '_', ' ' };
```

I am not able to find any way to bypass '/'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent xss perfectly without using any encoder jar,
Cast the input string to java object of Date datatype, then cast it back again to string, if you really want the output in string.

If you really want to use encoder jar, 
use any simple method like Encode.forHtml(str) which doesnot encode '/'.

Comment: I liked the idea of casting into Date type, But I was looking for more general solution like escaping more values rather than date and bypassing some other characters ('\', '$') as well.